# Merge Branch into a Directory GIT

Tags: git, github, git-merge, git-branch

I have main branch named `Project`

Then I have a branch named `payment` which consists all the project files of the application

I want to merge the branch `payment` into my main branch but inside a folder/directory

In other words
Project branch -> Payment Application(folder) -> files of the payment branch

Answer (score 1):

First time:

```
git checkout project
git merge --no-commit -s ours payment
git read-tree -u --prefix=payment/ payment
git commit
```

Thereafter:

```
git checkout project
git merge -s subtree payment
```

and you're probably fine making that the default merge strategy for your project branch, puns seem unlikely:

```
git config branch.project.mergeoptions '-s subtree'
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer is prefix=folder/branch ?
and is subtree branchname?

It would be great if you could edit the answer with ```Payment Application``` as the folder name

Comment: I think in `--prefix=payment/` the `payment` refers to the destination directory you are merging into. Then the `payment` at the end of that line is the branch name.