# Git merge diverged directory from branch into a new renamed directory while keeping original

Tags: git, git-merge

Context: I have a big repo with lots of little creative coding projects in different directories. Sometimes I modify a directory on a branch and it turns into something new I want to keep in addition to the original.

In my repo I have a directory `Dir` holding a project.

On branch `Experiment`, `Dir` has diverged from `master`. I actually now want to keep both variants of `Dir`, the original on `master` and the one on `Experiment`.

**How can I end up on `master` with both its existing `Dir` and also a directory `ExperimentDir` that has the version of `Dir` currently sitting on branch `Experiment`?**

In effect, I'm forking a directory within a single repo. I could just copy and paste, but **I want to keep the history of changes to these files from both branches**.

I tried on branch `Experiment` to `git mv Dir ExperimentDir` and then merge into `master`. But I'm left with a convoluted merge conflict as git is trying to merge in the rename to avoid duplication.

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution by adapting jthill's answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/66609162. That question and answer address a more general question which is why I couldn't find it. It feels worth answering this specific scenario: merging a single directory into a renamed directory without combining it with the original.

1. On branch `Experiment`, delete everything apart from the divergent directory. Move contents of that directory to the root and delete the now empty directory. Commit.
2. In git:

```sh
git checkout master
git merge --no-commit -s ours Experiment
```

> `Automatic merge went well; stopped before committing as requested`

```sh
git read-tree -u --prefix=ExperimentDir/ Experiment
git commit -m "Merge Experiment subtree into ExperimentDir"
git checkout master
git merge -s subtree Experiment
```

> `Merge made by the 'subtree' strategy.`

Note that when logging the `ExperimentDir` directory I need to use `--follow` to find the history, but when logging `Dir` I need to *not* use `-follow` to avoid getting the history of `ExperimentDir` included as well.